# Im making an instagram bot that messages users who liked a specific post, however it doesnt click on the profile after it clicks the liked link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing an Instagram bot to streamline the process of messaging users who liked a particular post. The script utilizes Selenium for web automation, interacting with Instagram's web interface to navigate through the login process, open a specific post, and click on the "Likes" link to access the list of users who liked it. However, I'm encountering a persistent issue where the script fails to click on the profile pictures of users within the list after clicking the "Likes" link. This problem could stem from dynamic loading of elements, changes in the HTML structure, or asynchronous operations on Instagram's end. I'm currently exploring ways to refine the script, considering Instagram's dynamic web structure, to ensure seamless interaction and achieve the intended automation of messaging users who liked the post.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException
import time
from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch

# Function to send a direct message
def send_direct_message(api, user_id, message):
    api.direct_v2.send_direct_item(
        user_id=user_id,
        item_type='text',
        text=message
    )

# Function to get the user ID from the profile URL
def get_user_id_from_url(api, profile_url):
    username = profile_url.split('/')[-2]
    user_info = api.username_info(username)
    return user_info['user']['pk']

# Define the usernames and passwords for the accounts
account_credentials = {
    'username': 'password',
    'username': 'password',
    'username': 'password'
}

# Initialize the Instagram Private API
def initialize_api(username, password):
    api = Client(username, password)
    return api

# Number of users to message for each account
num_users_to_message = 5

# Initialize the Firefox driver outside the loop
options = Options()
options.headless = False  # Set to True if you don't want the browser to open
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

try:
    # Create and manage sessions for each account
    for username, password in account_credentials.items():
        try:
            # Open the Instagram login page
            driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
            print(f"Opened Instagram login page for {username}")

            # Allow all cookies if the button is present
            try:
                allow_cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Allow all cookies']"))
                )
                allow_cookies_button.click()
                print("Clicked 'Allow all cookies'")
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the overlay to be dismissed
            except TimeoutException:
                print("No cookie overlay found or already dismissed")

            # Log in to Instagram
            username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username'))
            )
            password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')

            username_input.send_keys(username)
            password_input.send_keys(password)

            login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
            login_button.click()

            print(f"Logging in as {username}")
            # Wait for the login to complete
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Home']"))
            )

            print(f"Successfully logged in as {username}")

            # Open the specified Instagram post
            post_url = 'post'
            driver.get(post_url)
            print(f"Opened Instagram post: {post_url}")
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the post page to load

            # Click on the "Likes" link to open the list of people who liked the post
            try:
                likes_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/liked_by/')]"))
                )
                likes_link.click()
                print("Opened the list of people who liked the post")

                # Click on the profile pictures of people who liked the post
                profile_pictures = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title and starts-with(@href, '/')]//img"))
                )

                # Click on the profile picture of the top user and send a direct message
                for i in range(min(num_users_to_message, len(profile_pictures))):
                    try:
                        profile_pictures[i].click()
                        print(f"Clicked on the profile of user {i + 1}")

                        # Initialize the Instagram Private API
                        api = initialize_api(username, password)

                        # Get the username and user_id of the user
                        user_username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2").text
                        user_id = get_user_id_from_url(api, driver.current_url)

                        # Send a direct message
                        message_text = "Hello! This is an automated message."
                        send_direct_message(api, user_id, message_text)
                        print(f"Sent a direct message to {user_username}")

                        # Go back to the list of people who liked the post
                        driver.back()
                        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the page to load

                    except Exception as ex:
                        print(f"Error sending direct message: {ex}")

                print(f"Sent direct messages to the top {num_users_to_message} users for {username}")

            except TimeoutException:
                print("TimeoutException: Likes link not found")

        except TimeoutException as e:
            print(f"TimeoutException: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the browser window outside the loop
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Instagram employs sophisticated mechanisms to detect and block bot-like activities. Your script's behavior might trigger these mechanisms, leading to unexpected behavior or blocks.